# team foundation server chart size

Tags: charts, tfs, dashboard

There is a chart in team foundation server that is exactly what we would like to see. However I do not find a way to expand the default size or change the size of the axis titles per row. [desired chart only larger with larger titling area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zt6w3.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

There is no where to expend the default size or change the char size on TFS web access.

As an alternative, you can [create Excel reports from a work item query](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/report/excel/create-status-and-trend-excel-reports). In Excel, you can resize the Pivot Chart. Check my example below:

[image]

Comment: The lack of a built-in size change support is making life harder. Especially when one needs to deal with graphs that have time axis. Is there a place where we can vote for the feature?